# Why does ember use the same controller instance on separate visits to a route?

Tags: ember.js

Problem:

I have a conceptual problem with re-using an old controller instance when the user re-enters the route. In many examples, the controller stores the state of user interaction in instance variables. When the user re-enters the controller those should be reset, but there is no clear mechanism for doing so.

So, there must be a good reason to use a single controller instance. What is it?

How I arrived at this issue:

I ran into a bug in out Ember app, where the controller keeps local state that got out of sync based on the user actions elsewhere. The controller maintains a state whether the user is editing the "name" of a "case". When the controller is instantiated, that is set to "true", but when the user cancels, it's set to "false". Then the user goes away to a different route and comes back to the same route. I get the same controller instance that already has "false" for editing the name. I would expect to have "true" instead.

Ember v.s. Rails:

I'm coming from Rails perspective where controller is instantiated for every request. There is no shared controller state between requests. All instance variables are local to the request, so they can be used safely.

Back to the question:
Why does ember use the same controller instance on separate visits to a route?

Answer (score 4):

The role of a controller in ember and in rails are very different. In rails, as you know, the controller is used as a conduit for the request to prepare the data for presentation. If you consider the use case in ember, this is a role that is primarily played by the router.

In your example you mention that the edit state has gotten out of sync. You can solve this problem in a variety of ways, for example you could move the edit state to the model, so instead of `isEditing`, you'd call `model.isEditing` (or just `isEditing` if you are using an ObjectController). Another option would be to reset the state of the controller when entering the route.

Another example which should illustrate this difference is a save button on a form. Initially you might think "Oh, I'm going to put a save action on my controller". This is logical, when you're thinking like a rails developer, but saving a model is the responsibility of the router (especially if it results in changing the current route as this is something that's intentionally hard to do from a controller).

In ember the role of a controller is as a conduit between the model and the view. The fact that controller instances are re-used is a little confusing, but really isn't that important. When you change or return to a route the *model/context* of the controller is different, and that is where the state of the view should live... in the model.

Comment: Btw, I'm quite new to ember. This is one of the things I found most confusing, especially because the term is overloaded. If I'm wrong in anyway I'd appreciate some feedback from people with more ember experience.

Comment: In a controller you can call `transitionToRoute` to change the route.

Comment: "saving a model is the responsibility of the router" - that sounds surprising to me. I've never seen that.

Comment: Using model.isEditing doesn't solve my issue. Controller state represents the state of user interaction. This controller allows to edit only parts of the model at once. The model might be in "isEditing" state all the time.

Comment: Using "reset" on controllers seems reasonable. However, if this is what it takes, I'd have to have reset on ALL of my controllers to avoid accidental sharing of state between visits.

Comment: The other option is to use `setupController` to set the state of the controller when you enter the route.

Comment: This is really tough for Rails developers, I think, because of the name "controller". The phrase that helped me was that in ember, "a controller decorates a model". Maybe try and change your concept away from seeing the controller as holding state and think of it more like a way to mix actions and blocks into a model. The model is the stateful portion so putting properties in there is ok.

Comment: Also, consider how knowing a controller is a singleton could be a benefit. ie. If you had a select box on a Post page to maybe filter Comments, you could store the selected filter value on the postController. Since that will not change when you go to another post's route (cause only the model changes), your filter selection will persist.

Answer (score 1):

Although controllers are usually singleton, when you use {{render}} with a specified model you will get a newly instantiated controller.  See [rc2 release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/30/ember-1-0-rc2.html) under "Using Render with Multiple Models".  I'm new to Ember and this difference confused the heck out of me.

Using a singleton controller when trying to keep per-model-instance user interaction state seems tricky.  As jonnii said, you can put the state on the model, and that works but it cruds up the data model.  The other thing I have tried is to put a map in the controller (keyed by model, value is an object of user interaction state) but this seems like a clumsy reimplementation of something I'd expect the framework to provide.  Still working on this...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That tells me that instantiating multiple controllers isn't the end of the world. That brings the question again - why wouldn't I do that on router navigation?

Comment: {{render}} is the way to go. Best docs I've seen for it are the RC2 blog post http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/30/ember-1-0-rc2.html